# Changing default help key behavior

Tags: cocoa

I have a subclass of a NSWindowController. In my subclass, I have a keyDown: method.

When I press the Help Key on the keyboard, my keyDown: method is not called and I would like it to be as I need to do something custom.

Right now, when I press the help key, the cursor changes to a question mark.

Anyone know how to override the default behavior of the help key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've been able to find is to use the NSContextHelpModeDidActivateNotification to detect when this mode is entered.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(helpContextModeActivated:)
                                             name:NSContextHelpModeDidActivateNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

When the selector is called, simply call:

```
[NSHelpManager setContextHelpModeActive:NO];
```

to deactivate the mode and change the cursor back.

Comment: Hi. This is quite late, isn't it, especially for someone different =P This code works for disabling the Help behavior, but it doesn't send the original keyDown: to the key window's first responder. I could synthesize a fake keyDown: and send it myself, but I want to err on the side of caution, and the docs say "typically": is it possible for this notification to be sent by something other than the Help key? For example, some other keyboard shortcut, or key+mouse combination, or GUI program in the system? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind; [this fixes it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24101192/3408572), and doesn't require watching for notifications to boot. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is a broken holdover from NextStep.

I filed [a bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=38) about this in June 2006. It was closed as “Behaves correctly”, pointing out that this was a “context-sensetive help mode”, with the note that Apple keyboards no longer have Help keys.

I objected on the basis that there is no documentation of this for either users or developers and the help mode thus never under any circumstances provides actual help. It was then reclassified as a duplicate of bug #3776278. Last I checked (radarweb is currently down) this hadn’t changed.

I suggest filing a duplicate bug report on general principle, but don’t put too much effort in it since it will be ignored.