# How do I detect keyUp: in my NSView with the Command key held?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my NSView subclass, when I type, for example, Command+J, I see the `flagsChanged:` for Command being pressed, then a `keyDown:` for J... and then the `flagsChanged:` for Command being released. I never see a `keyUp:` for J.

I tried overriding `performKeyEquivalent:`, which looked like it did what I want, however that gets sent before the `keyDown:`!

So is there something else I'm missing to catch the `keyUp:` events?

No sample program this time, sorry. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ran into this issue a while ago. The problem seems to be that NSApplication is eating up the keyUp (or flagsChanged) for the Cmd key.

There are actually two solutions I found.
The first is overriding NSApplication as also described here:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2003/Oct/msg00442.html

The other is to do some own logic to detect the key up of the Cmd key as described here:

[Command-Key-Up Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000983/command-key-up-cocoa)

However, this second option might not work as you don't want to detect the Cmd keyUp but rather the J keyUp. This should be possible with the first solution though.

Comment: The first one works fine for me; in fact, it also resolves my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072250/changing-default-help-key-behavior/4078542#comment37162930_4078542) without needing to do anything that the answer I'm replying to does. Thanks! ([The code I have now, for reference.](https://github.com/andlabs/ui/blob/bc848f5c4078b999dbe6ef1cd90e16290a0d1c3a/delegateuitask_darwin.m#L46))

Comment: What if I'm subclassing `NSOpenGLView` instead of `NSView`? I think it will probably break something if I change `NSOpenGLView` to `NSApplication`. Any ideas?